# Show that a group of that order exists having this property.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

> Let $G$ be a finite group having an element of order $k$, for each $1 \leq k \leq 10$.
> What is the smallest possible order of $G$? Show that a group of that order exists
> having this property.

**My attempt:**

Since for each $a\in G$ order of $a$ divides order of $G$,  $|G|=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]=2520$. This is the smallets possible order of $G$ (it is right?). Now

> Show that a group of that order exists
> having this property.

I think one way to prove this would be by considering cyclic subgroups, but I'm not sure. my idea is this: If $|G|=2520$ and $a\in G$ has order $k$ $(1\leq k\leq 10)$, then $|\left \langle a \right \rangle| \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$, so the group of that order exists having this property.

Comment: Yes, the lcm of these numbers is $2520$. By Lagrange we cannot take a smaller order.

Comment: Your conclusion for the second part is not correct:  a group of order $2520$ might have, for example, an element of order $2520$; and in fact this is an easy place to look for an example.  (@DietrichBurde said this more explicitly [seconds earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979145/show-that-a-group-of-that-order-exists-having-this-property#comment8209960_3979145).)

Comment: @LSpice Any hint for solve it?

Answer (score 1):

As $2520=2^3\,3^25\,7$, you simply have to consider the product of cyclic groups
$$\mathbf Z/8\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/9\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z.$$

Comment: Why not write it as $\mathbb Z/2520\mathbb Z$, as @DietrichBurde [suggests](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979145/show-that-a-group-of-that-order-exists-having-this-property#comment8209960_3979145)?

Comment: You  can, applying the Chinese remainder theorem, but this form makes more obvious the required elements with prescribed order do exist.

Comment: @Bernard This you mention, wouldn't it be just an example of what they ask of me? Or does it work like that too?

Comment: @Hopmaths: I'm not sure what you're asking. Maybe whether there exist other examples with the same order?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, I meant that. is that I also thought about that group, but I imagined that it was only an example

Comment: In the context of finite abelian groups, I think the structure theorem thereof shows it is the only minimal example. For nonabelian groups, I don't know.